# matrix2SpectraObject in ChemoSpec

Tags: r, spectra

I can't seem to produce a Spectra object.
The file I am using look like this:

[image]

Column A: Wavelength
All other columns: Individual measurements

```
FTIR<- read.csv(file="FTIR_20190328_test.csv", header = T)
matrix <- matrix2SpectraObject (gr.crit =c("ID"),
                     gr.cols = c("auto"),
                     freq.unit = "Wavenumber",
                     int.unit = "Absorbance intensity",
                     descrip = "Treatment effects on necromass spectra",
                     in.file = "FTIR_20190328_test.csv",
                     out.file = "necro",)
```

I am getting error:

```
Error in matrix2SpectraObject(gr.crit = c("ID"), gr.cols = c("auto"),  : 
  could not find function "matrix2SpectraObject"
```

Can someone help me get this to work?
Thanks.

Described above.
I think it has something to do with the ID_ naming?

Comment: Your error says it cannot find the function `matrix2SpectraObject`, which suggests you have not yet called `library(ChemoSpec)` before running your code. Alternatively, try `ChemoSpec::matrix2SpectraObject`

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks for the info! Now I am getting this error:
Reading 1 file(s)...
Assigning 0 spectra to 1 group(s)...
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In .groupNcolor(spectra, gr.crit, gr.cols, mode = "1D") :
  There was no match for gr.crit value ID among the file names.
> sumSpectra(FTIR)
Error in UseMethod("sumSpectra") : 
  no applicable method for 'sumSpectra' applied to an object of class "data.frame"